# How to calculate press load for an interference fit with no friction coefficient between the materials (shaft & hub)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, stresses, solid-mechanics, friction, bearings

Press-fit load calculation always takes friction into consideration and gives you the load expression as follows,

$$F = µ\cdot PA$$

where µ is the friction coefficient, P ([Interference Pressure](https://www.ggbearings.com/en/tribou/design-press-fit-installation#:%7E:text=F%20%3D%20p%20%C3%97%20A%20%C3%97%20%CE%BC)) is the pressure developed due to interference and A being the total surface area in contact (after pressing).

So, if the friction coefficient is 0, does it mean the load required to create the press fit is 0?

Intuitively it doesn't seem like that, because there should be a minimum force to at least deform the hub/shaft. But that case isn't included in the formula mentioned above.

I'm asking this just to know the upper bound/lower bound of the press load.

Also, the formula doesn't take into account the entry chamfer of the hub. Without the chamfer, the case would be similar to that of punching sheet metals and not press-fit.

I have worked out the case that includes the chamfer, with no friction acting on the shaft. I'm not sure if it is a correct approach, but there's that. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Press-fit force calculation without friction]

Comment: Don't need a chamfer if you heat (or cool) one and do the opposite to the other. I fitted new valve guides by putting the new guides in the freezer and the head in the oven.

Comment: "So, if the friction coefficient is 0, does it mean the load required to create the press fit is 0?" - There is zero loads required to create the fit, but to maintain the fit by the friction on the contact faces. Without friction, the block will fall through.

Comment: @r13 I agree that without friction, the block will simply just fall. But don't you have to apply force for the deformation at least. How can the shaft enter the hub if there is a physical barrier and you are not providing any external load? I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: @SolarMike Yes, you are right. You don't need the chamfer if you are just heating the hub, or cooling the shaft. But my question here is about direct insertion with the help of a servo/hydraulic press.

Comment: My understanding of this equation of force is for the "best fit", not punch., if friction is zero on the contact faces, the element will simply fall by its own weight.

Comment: Coulomb friction applies only to sliding; in this case sliding inside the fit.  The formula that you have says that P is the normal reaction pressure due to the press fit, and the resistance to slip depends on the friction coefficient and the normal pressure.

Comment: @r13 yaa even I understand it as a force required to disengage the shaft out of the hub. But on the same expression is used for engagement as well, and that's what confuses me. Also, I just wanna know the expression of force needed to create a press fit. What would happen after the engagement is not my concern. I don't mind if the block falls after it is inside the hub. I hope you understand what I'm trying to convey here.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee I don't understand what you are trying to say. I'm sorry. What I'm asking is what would happen to the press-fit force if the friction coefficient is 0? And what would be the expression of that force?

Comment: Since the press-fit method is entirely based on expansin and friction between the mating parts, I don't understand why you ask this question. See the link for tolerance of the press-fit. https://www.engineersedge.com/calculators/machine-design/press-fit/press-fit-equations.htm

Comment: theoretically if the frictional coefficient were zero, you would still need to deform the materials due to it being an interferance fit.  forces lose a lot of meaning but you should still be able to calculate a difference in energy from structural properties.

Comment: @Kaushik:  The problem is that zero friction is not physically observed, so we have little intuition on what should happen under such a condition.  First, the part will be able to slide up and down in the sleeve.  Second, it will be able to rotate in the sleeve.

Comment: @r13 By expansion do you mean thermal expansion? If yes, then it is not always locked with the help of expansion/contraction due to temperature difference. We can apply a force with the help of a servo/hydraulic press to create a press-fit. That's what we do at our company. Throwing the practical stuff out of the window, I just want to know the expression for the force required to make a press-fit and the degree of correctness in my approach.

Comment: @Abel Yaa exactly. There should be a force to deform the shaft/hub. But I can't find any source on the internet that talks about such cases (though impractical). But practical stuff comes from ideal scenarios. That's how we get a range of acceptable values.
And what do you mean when you said "Forces lose a lot of meaning"? But I like the idea of the energy approach. Would you be so kind to make an attempt to find the force using energy equations? Thank you!

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee Yaa, there are no practical cases with 0 friction. It will lose its application if there is 0 friction. But I'm curious anyways.

Comment: as Solar Mike mentioned, there are interferance fit cases without friction.  these are not press fit cases though.  There is plenty of literature regarding calculating stresses from deformations and also relating such to energy.  Forces lose meaning in that a force is directional. If I asked how much force was required to expand a metal ring to a specific larger diameter, you built a fixture to do so and came up with a force, I could build a different fixture and claim you were wrong.  As long as we were doing it evenly over the ring, the stresses incurred would be pretty close though.

Comment: @Kaushik: The process of creating an interference fit generates a radial force.  That force is balanced in the two materials.  Without friction, any motion is possible in the other directions.  However, these are not directly relevant to your problem,  which is "how much pressure is enough for a press fit (and how fast can the pressure be applied)".  For that, you need to specify the amount of interference before the pressure is applied, the materials involved, and use elasticity theory, e.g., https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0924013617302509

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee My question isn't regarding the pressure. It is about the force.

Comment: @Abel If both the fixtures provide at least F_min, then it shouldn't be a problem. Force provided below F_min would just not work out for expanding the ring.

Comment: @Kaushik:  It's rarely that a point force is applied when doing an interference fit.  It's always a force over an area, which is called pressure/traction.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee but to select a servo/hydraulic press you should know if the press can handle the load. For that you should calculate the force required for press-fit.

Comment: @Kaushik:  The pressure has to be converted into force, not the other way round.  You have to know the dimensions of your part.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee I know. That's how I calculated in the attached image. You can just tell me in terms of variables. Doesn't have to be a number

Comment: The easiest way to a rough guess is to use thick-wall cylinder theory to compute the pressure needed to compress the shaft by $\delta$ in the radial direction.  Then use Coulomb friction to find the resistance, after converting the pressure to a force around the surface of the cylinder.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee but the question is to find the force if there is no friction.

Comment: @Kuashik: That question has been answered many times earlier.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee I couldn't see anyone giving me the expression for the force.

Comment: Read the paper.  You can download it via scihub.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee I had gone through the paper earlier and it doesn't give an expression for force assuming friction to be zero.

Comment: That's because, as discussed earlier, the force is 0. If you're considering an initial plastic deformation, then there is no analytical solution, and you'll have to get a numerical answer.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee There force required to disengage would be 0. But to create the joint 0 force sounds very illogical. An analytical solution is possible to derive in my opinion. I mean, it doesn't seem too complicated. That's what I have tried in the attached image. But I'm not sure if I'm missing something

Comment: Your model is incomplete because it assumes that all materials involved are rigid and only a balance of forces is enough.  Your intuition is telling you something that's not about friction, but about deformation.  I will add a temporary answer to illustrate the point.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee that would be really great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the initial situation shown in the image below. We are interested in the area in yellow.

[image]

After the load is applied, the deformed system will have the form shown below.  Note that both components have deformed.

[image]

Because of the complications in the deformation, an approximation is typically made.  A model of the deformation is shown below.  An assumption made in the model is that the load needed to overcome the bump at the end is much smaller than that needed to expand the annular sleeve and contract the cylinder.  So you are left with the need to solve a thick cylinder elasticity problem.

[image]

You can always play with the initial shapes to reduce unwanted effects and lip formation.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. That was a good explanation and I also had thought the same with regards to the simultaneous deformation of shaft and hub. But my model takes into account the forces at any given instant, assuming that the deformation is uniform (as in, deformation is in the form of chamfer in both mating parts along with a straight radial compression and expansion). And since the force acting on both the mating parts is same, I just considered the shaft for easy calculation of compressive force.

Comment: @Kaushik the problem with your model is that you dont know what the value of theta will ultimately be. So your back to the same problem as the friction formulation. You have just replaced mu with tan theta and you still dont know the value of the greek letter. See theta inside the object is nolonger the same as in the chamfer.

Comment: The good thing with the friction formulation is that its easy to measure the value in the workshop.

Comment: Ok, so let's take an example where the friction coefficient for a certain material combination is 0.01 for a given interference. This makes the value of force very little. Which is very counterintuitive.

Comment: @joojaa: Both chamfers and friction are second-order effects.  Chamfers ease the initial mating of parts and remove stress concentrations.  Friction is dissipative.  The first-order problem needs to be solved first.  The standard mechanics way to solve the first-order problem is energy balance: to balance the work done by the applied load with the deformation energy created in the system. After that, friction and chamfers can be added to make the system more realistic.

Comment: @Kaushik friction is a experimental value only frictions taken in similar situations apply to the first formula presented in the question. I agree with Biswajit that you either need to do it thisway or push a pin through experimentally to get a usable friction value for your application which has rolled the sliging friction and the pushing out of material into one lumped value. Because in some usable range two identical pins that only change in size are equally predictable by formula

Comment: @joojaa understood

Answer (score 0):

Friction coeficient is not one quantity and one effect. It is an experimenttaly derived value that includes multiple different physical effects lumped into one.

Therefore, all deformation and all other effects in that formula is rolled into the friction coeficient. This includes surface roughness peak distribution, lubrication status, deformation, wear, etc. You could make a model that is more complicated offcourse that would account for the individual physical processes better but it would be more complicated

But yes for purposes of of the formula you present a friction of 0 would indicate that no deformation or surface contact happens.

Comment: I agree that friction coefficient will include all surface parameters. But would a zero friction really mean zero deformation? I have my doubts.

Comment: @Kaushik for the model you use yes. If you want a model that has parts of friction taken out of the friction lump you need to derive a different model. So its not generally true but it is true for this particular formulation.

Comment: can you give an example for the model. I'm not sure how to begin with.